# Fix an error in calculating interest in python 3.6

Tags: python

I want to calculate interest rate but I am not getting what I supposed to. I should get something like this:

```
>>> interest_calculator ()
Enter the following details .
Your initial amount : 5000
Number of years : 5
Annual interest rate ( as a percentage ): 2.35
Money after 1 year is 5117.5
Money after 2 year is 5237.76
Money after 3 year is 5360.85
Money after 4 year is 5486.83
Money after 5 year is 5615.77
Money growth after 5 years is ( as a percentage ) 12.32
```

The code is

```
def interest_calculator():
    i_amount=eval(input('Your initial amount:'))
    num_yr=eval(input('Number of years:'))
    anual_rate=eval(input('Annual interest rate as percentage:' ))
    money=0
    for i in range(1,num_yr+1): # 1 so that it begins from 1 and not 0
        money= i_amount+ i_amount*(anual_rate/100)*i
        #money=money+money*(anual_rate/100)

        print('Money after ',i,'year is',round(money,2))
    print('Money growth after', num_yr,'year is(as percentage',((money-i_amount)/(i_amount))*100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem with your code was you were always using the same initial amount for all years. While the amount for every year changes and accordingly interest should be calculated. I hope this update solves your problem:

```
def interest_calculator():
    i_amount=eval(input('Your initial amount:'))
    num_yr=eval(input('Number of years:'))
    anual_rate=eval(input('Annual interest rate as percentage:' ))
    money=i_amount
    for i in range(1,num_yr+1): # 1 so that it begins from 1 and not 0
        money=money+money*(anual_rate/100)
        print('Money after ',i,'year is',round(money,2))
    print('Money growth after', num_yr,'year is(as percentage',((money-i_amount)/(i_amount))*100)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help , i was forgetting  to set money=i_amount

Comment: @FarhanOmar if this solved your question, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're commenting out the code which can do the things you want.

The following code will give the result you want.

```
def interest_calculator():
    print("Enter the following details .")
    i_amount=eval(input('Your initial amount : '))
    num_yr=eval(input('Number of years : '))
    anual_rate=eval(input('Annual interest rate (as a percentage): ' ))
    money=i_amount
    for i in range(1,num_yr+1): # 1 so that it begins from 1 and not 0
        money=money+money*(anual_rate/100)
        print('Money after ',i,'year is',round(money,2))

    print('Money growth after', num_yr,'year is ( as a percentage ) ',round((((money-i_amount)/(i_amount))*100),2))
```

Comment: I tried that but then forgot to set money = initial amount

Comment: yes, it happens sometimes. Keep using python and keep contributing opensource community. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize `money` to `i_amount`, and use the commented-out line to update `money` instead of what you are using, you get the desired output (well, except that the growth rate is printed w/ more than 2 decimal places).

Comment: that was my mistake ,sometimes it is easy to do things on paper but more difficult to code it

Comment: The funny thing is, is that you DID code it, but for some reason commented it out (I assume because it didn't work w/ the initialization you had for `money`).

Comment: Yes ,you are right ,i couldn't figure it out the tried to changing my equation instead off working on coding. Any way it is easy to get in wrong direction when one doesn't have experience with something,thanks for all of guys .